# How to refresh credentials from google.oauth2.service_account.Credentials object?

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-api-python-client, service-accounts

I have an instance of `google.oauth2.service_account.Credentials`. How should I refresh these credentials. I get `creds.expired` as True.

Comment: Please edit your question and include [example] service accounts credentials shouldn't need to be refresh the client library should detect all that for you.

Comment: How to extract access_token from the credentials? Initially access_token is None, I need the access token in my script. In order to get token, I need to refresh the credentials

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While reading the docs [here](https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/google.auth.transport.requests.html#google.auth.transport.requests.Request), I got my answer. WE can refresh the credentials and get the token using following approach :

```py
import google.auth.transport.requests
import requests

request = google.auth.transport.requests.Request()

credentials.refresh(request)
```